# My RELEASE framework file is bigger than DEBUG framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multi-platform project for which I am creating a release framework. My release framework is bigger than the debug framework.

Following is the gradle task to create the framework:

```
task packForXcode(type: Sync) {

    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = 'RELEASE'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.iosArm64.binaries.getFramework(frameworkName, mode)

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask

    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The framework file generated when `mode = 'RELEASE'` is 5.3 kb but when `mode = 'DEBUG'` one is 3.8 Kb.

I have 2 questions:

- Is this expected ?
- How can reduce or remove unused code while creating such a framework like R8/pro-guard in android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result can be expected, as only release frameworks are embedding bitcode, debug ones have only bitcode markers(see some details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/faq.html#q-how-do-i-enable-bitcode-for-my-kotlin-framework)).
 Unused code should be already removed by the compiler, so there is no need to apply other tools here.